# I went to find Marmal to buy an Amulet of Mara but I already have 2 of them

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I tried to get married would it work because I know I have to buy one from Maramal.

Answer (score 4):

You would still need to talk to Maramal about marriage before the option becomes available. However, you don't necessarily need his Amulet of Mara- any Amulet of Mara will work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get married with any Amulet of Mara, not just Marmal's.

Answer (score -1):

You need to equip it and approach a freindly npc that is eligible for marriage.